# How to select a range of data from a column in a data frame such as the interquartile range?

Tags: r, statistics

Say I have a data frame df containing a column "A" taking real values. I know I can select only this column from the data frame and I know some commands to extract certain data from it e.g.

`df.A = df[df$A > 5 & df$A < 10, c("A")]`

However, how would I select for example the interquartile range, and more generally take the column minus the smallest X percent and largest Y percent of the values?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `quantile()`:

```
df.A <- df[df$A > quantile(df$A,0.25) & df$A < quantile(df$A,0.75), c("A")]
```

Comment: Thanks. Both answers are great. I am going to accept MattBagg's as it does not include the `subset` function (this is preferable for me).

Answer (score 1):

Use subset , see ?subset for more details. But it  is better to give a reproducible example and not use df as varaible name, there is a df function.

I reproduce an example

```
     dff <- data.frame(A= sample(1:100),B=sample(1:100))
```

I compute the quantile range

```
     qq <- quantile(A,probs=c(.025,.975))
```

I use subset for the selection

```
     subset(dff, A > qq[1] & A< qq[1],select=c('A'))
```